# Find the area of surface of revolution

Tags: calculus, integration

$y^2 = 1+x, 0 \leq x \leq 3$, rotated about the x-axis. This is really frustrating because the answer is wrong, and after redoing this problem, I get an answer that is still wrong, but different from my first answer....

$$\begin{align}
S &= \int_{0}^{3} 2\pi \sqrt{1+x} \sqrt{1 + \bigg( \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}}}\bigg)^2dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{1+x} \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x+4}}dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{1+x} \sqrt{\frac{4+x+1}{x+4}}dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{\frac{(x+1)(x+5)}{(x+4}}dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{\frac{(x+1)(x+4)+1}{(x+4}}dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{x+1+1}dx \\
& \textrm{substitution, u = x+2, du = dx, new bounds are 5,2} \\
&= s\pi \int_{2}^{5} = \sqrt{u}du \\
&= 2\pi \bigg[ \frac{2u^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3} \bigg]_{2}^{5} 
= 2\pi \bigg[ \frac{10\sqrt{5}}{3} - \frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3}\bigg]
\end{align}$$

But the answer is $\frac{\pi}{6} \bigg( 27\sqrt{27} - 5\sqrt{5}\bigg)$. I've double checked my work and I wasn't able to find my mistake or error. A second eye would be appreciated, thanks

edit: Fixed after mistake was found per answer below

$$
\begin{align}
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{1+x} \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{4x+4}}dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{1+x} \sqrt{\frac{4x+4+1}{4x+4}}dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{1+x} \sqrt{1}dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{1+x}dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_{1}^{4} \sqrt{u} du = 2\pi \bigg[ \frac{2u^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}\bigg]_{1}^{4} \\
&= 2\pi \bigg[ \frac{8 \sqrt{4} - 2}{3} \bigg] \approx 29.321
\end{align}$$

The textbook answer comes out to be about $\approx 67.604$ and wolphram alpha says it is $\approx 30.846$.

What the hell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an error:\begin{align}
S &= \int_{0}^{3} 2\pi \sqrt{1+x} \sqrt{1 + \bigg( \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}}}\bigg)^2\,dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{1+x} \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{\color{red}4x+4}}\,dx \\
\end{align}

Remark: also, it is possible that the solution given could contain mistake.

Comment: Please see my edits

Comment: There is another mistake, $2\pi \int_0^3 \sqrt{1.25+x}\,dx$. This will give you the wolfram alpha solution.

Comment: So $2\pi \int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{1+x} \sqrt{\frac{4x+4+1}{4x+4}}dx$ does not cancel out to be $\sqrt{1}$? Sorry, I can guess where the $1.25$ comes from, but I am not very certain about how you got that number.

Comment: Note that $$\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt{\frac{4x+4+1}{4x+4}}=\sqrt{(1+x)\cdot \frac{4x+5}{4(x+1)}}=\sqrt{\frac{4x+5}{4}}=\sqrt{x+\frac54}$$